# Unity3d Nav Mesh Agent avoiding newly created objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, unityscript

I'm creating a randomly generated terrain game where an enemy will follow after you. The terrain is built after launch through UnityScript. I am using Nav Mesh Agent for the enemies path finding but it is unable to find its way around the newly created objects. Is there a way to update the Nav Mesh after launch to accommodate the new objects? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from plugging someone else's asset store product, have you looked at the NavMeshObstacle component? It's intended for dynamic obstacles for avoidance with NavMeshAgents.

And no, you cannot (nor should need to) rebuild the NavMesh at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot rebuild navmesh. 
Maybe you should try with Astar pathfinding project http://arongranberg.com/astar/. It's great and used in a lot of commercial games. Free version has option to rebuild navigation graphs.
For next questions about unity3d try [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html).